# construct single CSS rule with @each

Tags: css, sass

I am looking for a way to construct a single CSS rule using severals parameters with Sass.

Let's say I want to create a mixin `transition` that takes targets as parameters to write one `transition` CSS rule (other parameters like transition time, etc. are constant).

```
@mixin transition($targets...) {
    @each $t in $targets {
        // construct the rule target by target
    }
    // and then transition: $rule; or something similar
}
```

I want to call it like

```
.foo {
    @include transition(color, width);
}
```

and get

```
.foo {
    transition: color 100ms ease-out, width 100ms ease-out;
}
```

Problem is, I was not able to find a way to construct a string by concatenation. Is it even possible, or is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
@mixin transition($targets...) {
    $items: "";
    @each $item in $targets {
        $i: index($targets, $item);
        @if $i == length($targets) {
          $items: $items + $item + " 100ms ease-out";
        }

        @else {
          $items: $items + $item + " 100ms ease-out, ";
        }
    }
    transition: unquote($items);
}
```

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/OzQRqG?editors=0100#0) (see compiled css)

1) Set a variable to hold the string

`$items: "";`

2) In the $each loop iteration get the index:

```
$i: index($targets, $item);
```

3) Concatenate each item to the `$items` variable. If it's the last item - then the string won't end with a comma - otherwise it will

```
@if $i == length($targets) {
  $items: $items + $item + " 100ms ease-out";
}

@else {
  $items: $items + $item + " 100ms ease-out, ";
}
```

4) Finally remove the quotes from the string with [unquote](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method)

```
transition: unquote($items);
```

### Usage:

```
.foo {
    @include transition(color, width);
}
```

Which produces compiled CSS:

```
.foo {
  transition: color 100ms ease-out, width 100ms ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!